# How to display fields in new line in same textBox in telerik reporting?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I am using Silverlight4 and Telerik Reporting Q3 2011. I am trying to Generate Reports of all Outlets. I used Table to display its fields. And I want to Display Full Address in same cell. How could I?

I Used following Experession to display Full Address in same cell.

```
 = Fields.AddressLine1
 + ", " + Fields.AddressLine2
 + ", " + Fields.Suburb
 + ", " + Fields.City
 + ", " + Fields.State
 + ", " + Fields.Country
```

I want do display this in same cell but want output like below..

```
 =====================
   Address
 =====================
  15A,
  xxxx xxxRoad,
  xxxxxx,
  xxxxxxxx
 ====================
```

But I m getting this

```
 =====================
   Address
 =====================
  15A, xxxx xxxRoad, xxxxxx, xxxxxxxx
 =====================
```

How do I get Output Which I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

made the Function NewLineFeeds() in this function I used Replace() Method to replace the specific string to newLine(\n) .

```
public static string NewLineFeeds(string text)
{
    string result = text.Replace(", ", "\n");
    result = result.Replace(", ", "\n");
    result = result.Replace(", ", "\n");
    return result;
}
```

and my Expression is

```
 =NewLineFeeds(Fields.AddressLine1 
  + ", " + Fields.AddressLine2 
  + ", " + Fields.Suburb 
  + ", " + Fields.City 
  + ", " + Fields.State 
  + ", " + Fields.Country)
```

This call the Function NewLineFeeds() and replace ", " to \n (new Line). Add this will work Fine..